# Find where clojure-contrib libs have moved to

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

Given how with future version of clojure are discouraging use of clojure-contrib as a single item - how do you find where things have moved to.

For example - this utility: http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/javadoc.browse-api.html#clojure.contrib.javadoc.browse/open-url-in-browser handy - but where has it moved to under the new scheme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all of the old "monolithic" contrib has been migrated to the new "modular" contrib. Some of it may never be migrated. It's up to the community to port the bits of the library they find useful.

You could try contacting the original maintainer to see if they have plans to migrate to the new library.

See http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Clojure+Contrib for an overview of the new contrib and where various things have ended up.

Comment: I think RTFM isn't a good answer. I had the same problem with priority-map and I still have not found it in the modular contrib packages. I came to the conclusion that the modular version does not yet contain everything from the old contrib, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: Indeed the new contrib doesn't contain everything from the old contrib. I think the list I linked to contains everything migrated so far.

Comment: so for the moment best avoiding 1.3 and sticking with contrib until the dust settles? it seems a somewhat embarrassing state of affairs. In theory better now than later, but it sure is irritating,

Comment: You could try contacting the original maintainer to determine their migration plans (if any). Easiest way is probably to post to the mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a better overview of the migration status in place:

http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go